# Is source code for editor open source?

Tags: dart-editor

I am new to dart and really like the editor, I mean, just at the editing features: auto-completion, function signature prompt, etc.

Is the underlining technology totally Eclipse? I am not familiar with Eclipse, but I wonder if Dart editor open source? Is it programmed in C++, Java or Dart?

I guess my question is - is it available relatively easy to grab used for an editor in my application? My application is to be done in Dart hopefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right at the top AND bottom of https://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/, which is the first search result on Google and DuckDuckGo, it says open-source. There's even a link to all the source code on Google Code. It appears to be mostly Python.

Before asking a question, make some effort to find things out for yourself.